# clone element N-times, depending on select option value

Tags: javascript, clone

I have a registration form where client can select via dropdown select box how many offices they want to see. So in that case I need my code to work next way - I select the option value (for example 4) and it clones me 4 office forms that I can fill.
I've already done the "add-new form" when opton is changed, now I need to clone this form as many times as the value in my select box.

```
<div class="inner6 register-form">bla-bla-bla, code with inputs and
    <div class="amount-offices fright">
        <div class="headers">Anzahl teilnehmende Standorte:</div>
        <select name="number_offices" class="number-offices" style="padding: 5px 5px 6px 5px;border: 1px solid #76ab26;margin-right: 10px;margin-bottom: 15px;">
            <?php for ($i=1 ; $i <=1 2; $i++) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <?php echo $i; ?>
            </option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hidden form which I copy and append into my main form

```
<div class="copy-area">
    <div class="register-form-extra">bla-bla-bla, code with inputs</div>
</div>
```

and js

```
$('.number-offices').change(function(){
    var extraForm = $(".register-form-extra").wrap("<div>").parents('.copy-area').html();
    var officesAmount = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $('.copy-form').find('.register-form-extra').remove();
    $('.register-form').after(extraForm);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.number-offices').on('change', function () {
    var parent = $('.register-form');
    parent.find('.register-form-extra').remove();
    var num = parseInt(this.value);
    var tmpForm = $(".copy-area .register-form-extra:eq(0)");
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        parent.append(tmpForm.clone());
    }
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/f1e5bhcq/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, just come to the same solution, but yours looks more readable!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```js
$('.copy-area').hide();
$('.number-offices').change(function() {
  var officesAmount = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  var e = $('.copy-area .register-form-extra').eq(0);
  $('.copy-area .register-form-extra').remove();
  for (var i = 0; i < officesAmount; i++) {
    e.clone().appendTo('.copy-area');
  }
  $('.copy-area').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inner6 register-form">

  <div class="amount-offices fright">
    <div class="headers">Anzahl teilnehmende Standorte:</div>
    <select name="number_offices" class="number-offices" style="padding: 5px 5px 6px 5px;border: 1px solid #76ab26;margin-right: 10px;margin-bottom: 15px;">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="copy-area">
  <div class="register-form-extra">

    bla-bla-bla, code with inputs

  </div>
</div>
```